# Prove that rotation matrix is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have rotation matrix defined as:

$$ R_\theta = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} $$

where rotation angle $\theta$ is constant. Matrix is orthogonal when

$$ Q^TQ=QQ^T=I  $$
$$ Q^T=Q^{-1} $$

Prove that rotation matrix $R_\theta$ is orthogonal. Also what is determinant of rotation matrix ?

Comment: What are you struggling with here? It seems like you have the key terms defined.

Comment: @KitterCatter Problem is you can write it like this $$ R_\theta R_{\theta}^T = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta \cos\theta - \sin\theta (-\sin\theta) & \cos\theta \sin\theta - \sin\theta \cos\theta \\ \sin\theta \cos\theta + \cos\theta (- \sin\theta) & \sin\theta \sin\theta + \cos\theta \cos\theta   \end{bmatrix}$$ but how do you move on from this to $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: It would be possible to throw this into calculator and you would get the correct result but doesn't mean i understand how do you calculate something like this ?

Comment: How do you calculate $$\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta=1$$ ?

Comment: For the off-diagonal elements, the result should be obvious from the commutativity of multiplication. For the diagonal elements, I suggest reviewing the trigonometry class that you either skipped or have forgotten. This is one of the first identities that one learns.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

You have simply to prove that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

and this is a simple consequence of the identity
$$
\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta=1
$$